# fix for NoReverseMatch error after integrating django package (django-audiotracks)

Tags: python, django, audio-player

I'm relatively new to django.. I'm trying to integrate the audiotracks package with my project. I'm trying to integrate the audiotracks package but I'm getting  NoReverseMatch error.
The documentation states..

Add `audiotracks` to your app
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit `settings.py` and add `audiotracks` to your list of
`INSTALLED_APPS`. Then synchronize your database with::

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

Edit your ROOT_URLCONF_ and add a piece of code similar to::

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    # Here we mount the app under /music. Feel free to use something else
    url("^music", include("audiotracks.urls")),
    # Some URLs require a Django username
    url("^(?P<username>[\w\._-]+)/music", include("audiotracks.urls")),
)
```

Visit the URL `/music/upload` to upload your first track.

the error occurs when i try to access music/upload..

here's the full traceback.

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/upload

```
Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['account',
 'music',
 'audiotracks',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Template error:
In template C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_audiotracks-0.2.5-py3.6.egg\audiotracks\templates\audiotracks\base.html, error at line 25
   Reverse for 'user_index' with arguments '('addemo1',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['music/tracks/(?P\d)/?$', 'music/tracks$']

```
15 :       .errorlist { color: red; list-style: none; display: inline; }
   16 :     </style>
   17 :     {% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
   18 :   </head>
   19 :   <body>
   20 :
   21 :   {% block subnav %}
   22 :       {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   23 :           <ul>
   24 :             <li><a href="{% url 'audiotracks' %}">{% trans 'Latest tracks' %}</a></li>
   25 :             <li><a href=" {% url 'user_index' user.username %} ">{% trans 'Your tracks' %}</a></li>
   26 :             <li><a href="{% url 'upload_track' %}">{% trans 'Upload track' %}</a></li>
   27 :           </ul>
   28 :       {% else %}
   29 :           &nbsp;
   30 :       {% endif %}
   31 :   {% endblock %}
   32 :
   33 :   {% if messages %}
   34 :   <ul class="messages">
   35 :     {% for message in messages %}
```

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_audiotracks-0.2.5-py3.6.egg\audiotracks\views.py" in upload_track
  109.     return render(request, "audiotracks/new.html", {'form': form})

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /music/upload
Exception Value: Reverse for 'user_index' with arguments '('addemo1',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['music/tracks/(?P\d)/?$', 'music/tracks$']

Comment: You cannot have followed that instruction; apart from anything else, `patterns` no longer exists in Django 1.11. Please show your full urls.py.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. i added the second url and it worked..@DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
    url(r'^music/', include('audiotracks.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\._-]+)/music', include('audiotracks.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        })
    ]
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```